# Parsing MySQL timestamp in PHP loop. How?

Tags: php, mysql

Here's a sample of my database table.

[image]

I am trying to get PHP to generate some HTML code from this screenshot that looks like this:

**2012**

**December 2012**

03 entry title 7

02 entry title 6

01 entry title 5

**November 2012**

04 entry title 4

03 entry title 3

02 entry title 2

01 entry title 1

**2011**

...and so on.

I just get lost on how to get PHP do know I hit a different year and/or month and create the format I described above.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by using instead unix timestamps and letting php convert them to readable format later on. That way you'd be able to set loops that run for as long as date("Y", $timestamp) has whatever value.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for further reference and details about the syntax.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can select year and month in MySQL:

```
 SELECT ent_title, YEAR(ent_timestamp) AS y, MONTH(ent_timestamp) AS m FROM my_table ORDER BY ent_timestamp DESC
```

And then loop through result checking previous month and yead values in PHP.